# How to draw a route between current location and destination within Mapkit Swift 3?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am trying to get the latitude en longitude coordinates of the CLLocationManager instance of the current user's location.

I have those two lines of code in my viewWillAppear method:

```
locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

Then I have a method called `startRoute` to calc the route from the current position to some specific annotation on the map. After that I draw the route between those paths. Unfortunately, this is working with two annotations on the map, but I can't get it work with the current location of the user and some annotation.

I tried below script, but when I print `print("LAT \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")` it will give me `0.0` as result.

```
func startRoute() {
        
        // Set the latitude and longtitude of the locations (markers)
        let sourceLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)
        let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: sightseeing.latitude!, longitude: sightseeing.longitude!)
        
        // Create placemark objects containing the location's coordinates
        let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: sourceLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
        let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationLocation, addressDictionary: nil)
        
        // MKMapitems are used for routing. This class encapsulates information about a specific point on the map
        let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
        let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
        
        
        // Annotations are added which shows the name of the placemarks
        let sourceAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        sourceAnnotation.title = "Times Square"
        
        if let location = sourcePlacemark.location {
            sourceAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        }
        
        
        let destinationAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        destinationAnnotation.title = "Title"
        destinationAnnotation.subtitle = "Subtitle"
        
        if let location = destinationPlacemark.location {
            destinationAnnotation.coordinate = location.coordinate
        }
        
        // The annotations are displayed on the map
        self.mapView.showAnnotations([sourceAnnotation,destinationAnnotation], animated: true )
        
        // The MKDirectionsRequest class is used to compute the route
        let directionRequest = MKDirectionsRequest()
        directionRequest.source = sourceMapItem
        directionRequest.destination = destinationMapItem
        directionRequest.transportType = .walking
        
        // Calculate the direction
        let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
        
        // The route will be drawn using a polyline as a overlay view on top of the map.
        // The region is set so both locations will be visible
        directions.calculate {
            (response, error) -> Void in
            
            guard let response = response else {
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
                
                return
            }
            
            let route = response.routes[0]
            self.mapView.add((route.polyline), level: MKOverlayLevel.aboveRoads)
            
            let rect = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
            self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(rect), animated: true)
        }
        
        
    }
```

At the top, directly after the class declaration I create the reference to `location manager` and 'CLLocation':

```
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
var currentLocation = CLLocation()
```

After all, this isn't working. Only when I change the sourceLocation to hardcoded coordinates, it will draw the route to the destination. What do I wrong or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

> but when I print `print("LAT \(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)")` it will give me `0.0` as result

Of course it does. What else would it do? You have a property

```
var currentLocation = CLLocation()
```

That is a zero location. You have *no* code that ever *changes* this. Therefore, it is *always* a zero location.

You say you want the

> current user's location

but nowhere do you have any code that *obtains* the user's location.

Comment: Okay, understandable. Do you have any hints to what I should look to update CLLocation?

Comment: The documentation is here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager